# Euler angles between two given coordinate systems

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to do a coordinate system transformation from a global (0,0,0) to a local element coordinate system. The local system's position and unit vectors are known.
My problem is that I need three Euler angles for the transformation matrix. I can only calculate the current angles between the global and local axis. But how do i get Euler angles with respect to the right order (e.g. Euler ZYZ rotation)? Is it possible to compute the Euler angles from that information?

[Link to IMAGE](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/57621/Unbenannt.PNG)

The global coord. system is green, the local is blue. The dashed blue system is the local system shifted to the point (0,0,0).

For the calculation of the transformation matrix, I used *localToGlobal3d.m* from [geom3d](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24484-geom3d):

> The transform is defined by:
>
> - CENTER: the position of the local origin into the World coordinate system
> - THETA: colatitude, defined as the angle with the Oz axis (between 0 and 180 degrees), positive in the direction of the of Oy axis.
> - PHI: azimut, defined as the angle of the normal with the Ox axis, between 0 and 360 degrees
> - PSI: intrinsic rotation, corresponding to the rotation of the object around the direction vector, between 0 and 360 degrees
>
> The resulting transform is obtained by applying (in that order):
>
> - Rotation by PSI   around he Z-axis
> - Rotation by THETA around the Y-axis
> - Rotation by PHI   around the Z-axis
> - Translation by vector CENTER
>
> This corresponds to **Euler ZYZ rotation**, using angles PHI, THETA and PSI.

I calculate the current angles between the local system's axis (e1,e2,e3) and the base axis via:

angleX = atan2d(norm(cross(e1,[1 0 0])), dot(e1,[1 0 0]))

angleY = atan2d(norm(cross(e2,[0 1 0])), dot(e2,[0 1 0]))

angleZ = atan2d(norm(cross(e3,[0 0 1])), dot(e3,[0 0 1]))

Thank you for your help!